# COUNTA(QUERY()) does not produce the desired result

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

The "mirror" sheet contains data.
[image]

Column B of the "bonus" sheet calculates the number of projects in a given month in which the specialist is involved.

```
=COUNTA(query(mirror!$A$2:$B, "select B where 
A <= date'"&TEXT(EOMONTH($A6,0),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
and
A >= date'"&TEXT($A6,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
ORDER BY B"))
```

On the "mirror" there are no projects for Dec 2020 and Jan 2021.
The counts function substitutes 1 for the "bonus" in these months, although 0 is expected.
[image]

I've already broken my head, I don't know how to overcome it. I would be grateful for ideas.

**Upd.** Column A of the "bonus" sheet contains dates in the form of 8/1/2020, 9/1/2020, 10/1/2020, etc. beginning of the month.
In column A of the "mirror" sheet, the dates can be 10/5/2020, 10/31/2020, i.e. not necessarily the end of the month.

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jL_rAlrjJP-_lN51xCQVLldyZi_ZnjOkPEcCZsklzGA/copy)

Comment: when you use COUNTA always wrap the next thing into IFNA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COUNTA counts an error as 1 (because it is "a non-null something"). So if your QUERY finds nothing, it will return an error — which will be counted as "one thing."

Try wrapping your QUERY in IFERROR, inside your COUNTA:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY(...)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(mirror!$A$2:$A)=MONTH(A2))*(YEAR(mirror!$A$2:$A)=YEAR(A2)))
```

[image]

Comment: You answered a question that I did not ask, but it tormented me. In QUERY, "where A = ..." we cannot use "EOMONTH (A) = ...", but we can use SUMPRODUCT. Thank you.